# How do I plot my function to a mesh

Tags: matlab, plot, triangulation, uncertainty

I am a new MATLAB user and I am trying to plot a function:

```
function [ uncertainty ] = uncertain(s1, s2, p)
%UNCERTAIN calculates the measurement uncertainty of a triangulation
% provide two coordinates of known stations and a target coordinate 
% of another point, then you get the uncertainty 
 [theta1, dist1] = cart2pol(p(1)-s1(1), p(2)-s1(2));
 [theta2, dist2] = cart2pol(p(1)-s1(1), p(2)-s2(2));
 theta=abs(pi-theta2-theta1);
 uncertainty = dist1*dist2/abs(sin(theta));
end
```

called with:

```
uncertain([0 0],[8 0],[4 4])
```

I get a single result.
But i want a whole surface and called:

```
x=-2:.1:10;
y=-2:.1:10;
z = uncertain([0 0],[8 0],[x y]);
mesh(x,y,z)
```

I get the error: "Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector."

How can I modify my code so that my function draws a surface?

Thanks in advance.
Ralf.

Answer (score 1):

First I think there's a mistake in your function: your `[theta2, dist2] = cart2pol(p(1)-s1(1), p(2)-s2(2));` should have th first `s1` being a `s2`.

Next, to get a vector answer out for your vector inputs, you have to change your `p(i)` (which selects the ith element of `p`) to `p(i,:)`, which will select the first ith *row* of `p`.

After that, you change multiplication (`*`) to element-wise multiplication (`.*`).

In summary:

```
function [ uncertainty ] = uncertain(s1, s2, p)
%UNCERTAIN calculates the measurement uncertainty of a triangulation
% provide two coordinates of known stations and a target coordinate 
% of another point, then you get the uncertainty
% target coordinates p are 2xn
% output uncertainty is 1xn
 [theta1, dist1] = cart2pol(p(1,:)-s1(1), p(2,:)-s1(2));
 [theta2, dist2] = cart2pol(p(1,:)-s2(1), p(2,:)-s2(2));
 theta=abs(pi-theta2-theta1);
 uncertainty = dist1.*dist2./abs(sin(theta));
end
```

The only changes are `p(i)` -> `p(i,:)`, and `*`->`.*` and `/`->`./`.

To get a surface, you use `meshgrid` to get all sets of `(x,y)` coordinates in a grid, flatten them into a `2xn` matrix for `uncertain`, and then expand them back out to the grid to plot. Example:

```
x=-2:.1:10;  % 121 elements
y=-2:.1:10;  % 121 elements
[xs,ys]=meshgrid(x,y); % xs and ys are each 121 x 121
zs = uncertain([0 0],[8 0],[xs(:) ys(:)]'); %get zs, being 1x(121*121) ie 1x14641
% Reshape zs to be 121x121 in order to plot with mesh
mesh(xs,ys,reshape(zs,size(xs)))
```

Note: you'll get lots of really big numbers because when `theta` is `0` or `pi` (or very nearly) because then you're dividing by (almost) 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I try to understand your modifications.

But the result is quite unexpected, because the 
angles should be near 90° and therefore the sin(angle) should be near 1.

I have an ugly java code producing an image like this:
http://pastehtml.com/view/bjowk6rbg.html

Comment: But my matlab code is yet missing a limit of 100 like: uncertainty = max (uncertain,100) coordinate wise
And the bounds should be narrowed down.

Comment: I have found another error in my code: the three angles must be 180° because they should be the three inner angles of the triangle (s1,s2,p).

Comment: But theta2 = cart2pol...  returns the outer angle at station 2, so theta must be theta2-theta1 ?

Comment: The code is sound in that it vectorises the version you wrote in your question - the unexpected results are to do with problems in your maths, I imagine (I can't help you). Why don't you try do the calculation by hand for a single `p`, verify that the result is what you expect, and then use your `uncertain` function agrees with it?